# Loading modules conditionally in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm working to make a library to work on both NodeJS and ReactNative. Some of the native NodeJS modules are not supported in ReactNative, so I tried to load them conditionally. This however doesn't work:

```
if (true) {
    require('a'); // module 'a' works in ReactNative
} else {
    require('b'); // module 'b' doesn't work in ReactNative
}
```

Unfortunately, BOTH require statements ad executed and loading of 'b' throws exception :(

Now I have the following options:

1. To create a new version of the library, specific for ReactNative, using only modules, which work there.
2. I've heard you can specify "react-native" in package.json and this would help to resolve this issue. However, I can't find documentation anywhere, is it documented somewhere?

How in general you would recommend to make my library to work in both Node and ReactNative?

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out - this is done using the "react-native" property in `package.json`. There you can either replace a module with another one, or to disable it for ReactNative (by setting its value to `false`). If you replace the module with another one, this module should be added to the list of dependencies too.

In the example above, for module `b` in `react-native` property you have to set `false` as value.

In package.json this might look like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "c": "^1.0.0"
},
"react-native": {
  "a": "c",
  "b": false
}
```

The code above will replace module `a` with module `c` in case of ReactNative and it will suppress the loading of module `b` (it will look like an empty object).

Comment: Is there a link to official documentation/sources?

Comment: Would also love to know where the documentation on this is.

Comment: No documentation for the "react-native" field, but it follows exactly the same specs as the "browser" field: https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code :

```
if (true)
{
    /* this module will get bundled in react-native app */
    require('a'); // module 'a' works in ReactNative
} else {
    let b = 'b'
    /* this module will not get bundled in react-native app */
    require(b); // module 'b' doesn't work in ReactNative
}
```

- > require('a')

  is included in the bundle by packager before executing the js bundle .It doesnt require at the runtime.
  react-native maintains a map of all the required modules and it
  generally replaces module name with id.
- > let b = 'b'
  >
  > require(b)

  is like a dynamic require which is not bundled by packager and is
  requested at runtime. It then searches this module in its map, as this map will not have this module, so react-native will throw error.

**Note:**
In your case

> if(true)

is a condition which will never execute the else part of if if-else, so react-native will never throw error like module not found.

Comment: Yes, this also works, thanks! However, the code looks odd, it looks more like a workaround over ReactNative's build system. Looking on it, I even don't know why does it work. It won't be easy to pass a review and any dev will try to "simplify" it. I think the other option, with 'react-native' in package.json it is more clear, isn't it?

Comment: @Joachim can you add content of package.json in your answer to understand complete structure ?

Comment: I have added the explanation of my answer .

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer and added some example code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a code like this example.

```
'use strict';

var _module;
if (true) {
  _module = 'lixo';
} else {
  _module = 'express';
}
var A = require('' + _module);
```

Comment: Have you tried that actually? This doesn't work, the result is: ExceptionsManager.js:63 Unknown named module: 'a'

Comment: In ReactNative it doesn't work, not that it won't work in general.